# How I can separate and collect different values in a list of attributes in HTML with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the next list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list" data="Paul"  data-id="2">Paul</li>
    <li class="list" data="Paul"  data-id="4">Paul</li>
    <li class="list" data="Peter" data-id="3">Peter</li>
    <li class="list" data="Peter" data-id="1">Peter</li>
    <li class="list" data="John"  data-id="11">John</li>
    <li class="list" data="John"  data-id="12">John</li>
</ul>
```

So, the goal is get:

```
Paul: 6 | Peter: 4 | John: 23
```

I'm trying with a .map in jquery like:

```
    $(function() {
        var total = 0;
        var counter = $('li.list').length;
        $('#resp').html(counter);

        var dataList = $("li.list").map(function() {
            var data = $(this).attr('data')             
            return data+$(this).data("id");
        }).get();

        mydata = dataList.join(";");
        alert(mydata)
    });
```

And this is returning:

```
Paul2;Paul4;Peter3;Peter1;John11;John12
```

How can I sort and sum for separte for get:

```
Paul: 6 | Peter: 4 | John: 23
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create Array with `Array.from()` and use `reduce` and return Object

```js
var result = Array.from($('ul li')).reduce((obj, e) => {
  obj[$(e).data('name')] = (obj[$(e).data('name')] || 0) + parseInt($(e).data('id'));
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list" data-name="Paul" data-id="2">Paul</li>
  <li class="list" data-name="Paul" data-id="4">Paul</li>
  <li class="list" data-name="Peter" data-id="3">Peter</li>
  <li class="list" data-name="Peter" data-id="1">Peter</li>
  <li class="list" data-name="John" data-id="11">John</li>
  <li class="list" data-name="John" data-id="12">John</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Fernando Urban You can also get this if you want https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/881/

Comment: This is the best answer for me. There is a way if you comment the code because some parts it does'nt clear for me in your code, also is works perfectly. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object to set property to `$(this).attr("data")`

```js
$(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var counter = $('li.list').length;
  var obj = {};
  $('#resp').html(counter);

  var dataList = $("li.list").map(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data');
    if (!obj[data]) {
      obj[data] = +$(this).data("id");
    } else {
      obj[data] += +$(this).data("id")
    }
    return data + obj[data];
  }).get();

  mydata = dataList.join(";");
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list" data="Paul" data-id="2">Paul</li>
  <li class="list" data="Paul" data-id="4">Paul</li>
  <li class="list" data="Peter" data-id="3">Peter</li>
  <li class="list" data="Peter" data-id="1">Peter</li>
  <li class="list" data="John" data-id="11">John</li>
  <li class="list" data="John" data-id="12">John</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Object and then do whatever you want with it:

```js
var people = {};

$("li.list").each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('data');
  people[name] = (people[name] || 0) + parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(people,0,4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list" data="Paul" data-id="2">Paul</li>
  <li class="list" data="Paul" data-id="4">Paul</li>
  <li class="list" data="Peter" data-id="3">Peter</li>
  <li class="list" data="Peter" data-id="1">Peter</li>
  <li class="list" data="John" data-id="11">John</li>
  <li class="list" data="John" data-id="12">John</li>
</ul>
```